# Unknown column 'quantityInStock' in field list (No PHP)

Tags: mysql

I know that this is the n-time this has been asked but the other questions were not useful (as far as i know).

I downloaded the DB `classicmodels` for some testing, but when i run the following query:

```
UPDATE `products` SET `quantityInStock` = 5 WHERE `productCode` = 'S10_1678';
```

It throws the error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'quantityInStock' in 'field list';
```

I used `SHOW COLUMNS FROM products;` to check the columns:

```
# Field,                  Type,       Null,   Key,   Default, Extra
'productCode',         'varchar(15)', 'NO',   'PRI', NULL,     ''
'productName',         'varchar(70)', 'NO',   '',    NULL,     ''
'productLine',         'varchar(50)', 'NO',   'MUL', NULL,     ''
'productScale',        'varchar(10)', 'NO',   '',    NULL,     ''
'productVendor',       'varchar(50)', 'NO',   '',    NULL,     ''
'productDescription',  'text',        'NO',   '',    NULL,     ''
'quantityInStock',     'smallint(6)', 'NO',   '',    NULL,     ''
'buyPrice',            'double',      'NO',   '',    NULL,     ''
'MSRP',                'double',      'NO',   '',    NULL,     ''
```

I tried with another query to verify: `UPDATE products SET productScale = '1:1' WHERE productCode = 'S10_1678';` but got the same error.

does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error?

Here's the DDL...

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
  productCode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  productName VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
  productLine VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  productScale VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  productVendor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  productDescription TEXT NOT NULL,
  quantityInStock SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  buyPrice DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  MSRP DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (productCode)
);
```

Comment: Yes. It shows me all the columns.

Comment: maybe your user doesn't have update permission on the db

Comment: @CodeBird my user is root. And i can update other tables.

Comment: and if you select that column does it select, or only select * works?

Comment: Yes, i can select that column.

Comment: You can download the DB from here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx I'll import the db again so i can make few more test. About the DOUBLE, that is how the DB was designed.

Comment: I reimported the DB and the UPDATE worked. This must be some kind of black magic. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this with mysql command line interface? Maybe the software, which you are using for sending queries, is the problem?

Can you try the same query in mysql command line interface?

Also, could it be that you are having a trigger, and that the error is not actually from the query, but from the underlying trigger?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help but i deleted the DB and reimported it and it worked fine. Anyway, thanks.